# How to use control logic in MCPPhaseGate

Tags: qiskit, programming

I need help with the MCPhaseGate. I am not able implement the control logic (i.e, the control function)with MCPhase gate similar to the RXgate shown below. It would be great help if someone can help me with it. The line `u=u.control(num_ctrl_qubits = k, ctrl_state = bitstring)` gives an error

```
  new_ctrl_state = operation.ctrl_state << num_ctrl_qubits | ctrl_state
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'str'
```

Not sure how to resolve this error?

```
import math
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import CPhaseGate
from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates.rx import RXGate
from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates.p import MCPhaseGate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 3
rotations = [math.pi, math.pi/2, math.pi/3, math.pi/4]

qcd = QuantumCircuit(5)
count = 0
for theta in rotations:
    binary = bin(count)[2:]
    print(binary)
    bitstring = ('0' * (k - len(binary))) + binary
    print(bitstring)
    u = RXGate(theta = theta).control(num_ctrl_qubits = k, ctrl_state = bitstring)
    qcd.append(u, qargs = [i for i in range(k+1)])
    count += 1

count1=0
for theta in rotations:
    binary = bin(count)[2:]
    bitstring = ('0' * (k - len(binary))) + binary
    print(bitstring)
    u = MCPhaseGate(lam=theta, num_ctrl_qubits=k)
    # u=u.control(num_ctrl_qubits = k, ctrl_state = bitstring)   ## Here is the Problem
    qcd.append(u, qargs=[i for i in range(k + 1)])
    count1 += 1

qcd.draw(output="mpl")
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit**

I want to know exactly where to use the phase gate.
I am planning to use it for the below circuit. Please advise whether I am using it at correct place.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems needed to be fixed:

1. There’s a typo in the second loop. Change `count` to `count1` in the row `binary = bin(count)[2:]`.
2. **The problem:** It looks like you are doing a double job with the controlled operations in the second loop. In the row `u = MCPhaseGate(lam=theta, num_ctrl_qubits=k)` you set `u` as a `MCPhaseGate` which is already a controlled gate (that corresponds to the 4 `mcp` gates we see in the circuit diagram). Then in the row after: `u=u.control(num_ctrl_qubits = k, ctrl_state = bitstring)`, you try to use the `control` method upon `u` again, that doesn’t make sense.
   **A solution:** use [`PhaseGate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PhaseGate.html) instead, in a similar fashion as in the first loop: `u = PhaseGate(theta = theta).control(num_ctrl_qubits = k, ctrl_state = bitstring)`.

Comment: Thank you @Ohad for this great help. I have edited the question a little. It would great if you can help with those questions also.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking in the edit section. Try to clarify it please.

Comment: Hi @Ohad, I want to know whether a term like   r * e ^i theta  , where "r" is less than 1 can be implemented by any gate in qiskit?

Comment: Using phase gates you can only induce phase to an amplitude (I.e “r” = 1). However sure it is possible to combine other gates into the circuit and basically create any valid statevector (Think of the surface of the Bloch sphere - any point on the sphere represent a valid statevector, and there are infinitely many points). In particular, the `Ugate` allows any desired rotation around the Bloch sphere.